# Is volatile a good practice to avoid race conditions in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I was wondering if in the specific case like this one, where we have bool flag that indicates if some service is available:

```
    private bool isAvailable;
    private void foo()
    {
        if(isAvailable)
        {
            isAvailable = false;
            DoSomething();
            isAvailable = true;
        }
    }
```

Is it sufficient to set bool field to be volatile in a multithreaded environment or is it better to use locks or even Monitor.

In this specific case, if the service is not available at the moment, it is not needed to wait for it to get available again.

Comment: That operation is not atomic, so making the bool volatile won't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not sufficient. Volatile is not enough for managing multithread, actually, volatile probably increase gap between expected result and actual result. Accessing variable (isAvailable) and modified it still leads to race condition.
You may use lock, semaphore or atomic operation for managing multithread operation.

```
private object myLock = new object;
private void foo()
{
    lock(myLock)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

or

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
private void foo()
{
    // DoSomething
}
```

@Fildor is right. I miss consept of question, hence, I edit my answer. Code which is below, if resource is not locked, code lock resource and do something, else it skip critical section.

```
private object myLock = new object;
private void foo()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen this attribute used, could you please explain it some more?

Comment: I have the feeling those solutions change the semantics of the OP. Both of them will block until the resource is available, then perform the action on it. The OP however, just needs to perform the operation if the resource is available. If not: don't care.

Comment: Synchronized wraps the entire method in a lock. If you want to read and learn more (there are alternatives lock management), you may check this link: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2013/04/16/2237/monitor-in-three-flavors-c-thread-synchronization

Answer (score 1):

Adem Catamak has it absolutely right, `lock`s are generally the way to go.

However, if your code is extremely performance critical you can have a look at using `MemoryBarrier` and `volatile`.

This page is extremely helpful in that regard: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

To add something to the `lock` answer, you can always abstract this away (not tested but you get the gist:

```
public class ThreadSafeObject
{
    private object _myObject; //Must be reference type
    public object MyObject
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_myObject)
            {
                return _myObject;
            }

        }
        set
        {
            lock (_myObject)
            {
                _myObject = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could even use generics to achieve this:

```
public class ThreadSafeGeneric<T>
{
    private T _myObject;
    public T MyObject
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_myObject)
            {
                return _myObject;
            }

        }
        set
        {
            lock (_myObject)
            {
                _myObject = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If there's something factually wrong with my answer I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers provide solutions to your problem, but just in case you were wondering why your solution won't work...

...Here's what could happen:

```
Thread A                                Thread B
--------                                --------
fetches isAvailable from memory
Tests the fetched value, it's true!     fetches isAvailable from memory
sets isAvailable=false                  Tests the fetched value, it's true!
calls DoSomething()                     sets isAvailable=false
...                                     calls DoSomething()
                                        ...
```

Comment: That makes sense! It seems that Monitor.TryEnter(lock) is the easiest solution for this problem.